# Accordion меню на CSS

Tags: html, css

Здравствуйте.

Я хотел бы сделать меню Accordion с помощью CSS.

Блок имеет такую структуру:

```html
<ul>
        <li>
                <a>Heading 1</a>
            <ul>
             <li><a>content</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
                 <a>Heading 2</a>
            <ul>
             <li><a>content2</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
                 <a>Heading 3</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a>content3</a></li>
                <li><a>content4</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
</ul>
```

Я набросал примерный CSS, но он естественно не работает.

```css
.accordion a + li{

        height: 0;
        overflow: hidden;

        -moz-transition: height 0.3s ease-in-out;

        -webkit-transition: height 0.3s ease-in-out;

        -o-transition: height 0.3s ease-in-out;

        transition: height 0.3s ease-in-out;

    }

    .accordion :target a + li{

        height: 100px;

    }
```

Вот как сделать так, чтобы это заработало? Заранее спасибо за любую помощью. )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```css
[id^=acc] {
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 0.3s;
}

[id^=acc]:target {
  max-height: 100px;
  transition: max-height 0.2s;
}
```

```html
<ul class="accordion">
  <li>
    <a href="#acc1">Heading 1</a>
    <ul id="acc1">
      <li><a>content</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#acc2">Heading 2</a>
    <ul id="acc2">
      <li><a>content</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#acc3">Heading 3</a>
    <ul id="acc3">
      <li><a>content</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое.

Comment: @Anatolly.CHA Пометьте как ответ.

Comment: @MikhailZhuykov ограничение. Ещё минуту подождать.